# Listings every entries for a Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, crud

I'm working on a project for Ruby on Rails. We have a Model nammed "Commerce" (it's in french, kind of 'shop') with a table in postgresql which contains at least 1500 entries. We generated it's CRUD views with 'rails generate scaffold_controller'. 
The problem is that while on the commerces#index, it can't shows all entries from the database. It shows near 50 of them and stop. Sometimes it show 55 of them but never more...

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for my english x)

Comment: Could you copy past your Commerce controller

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Actually, it was the reverse proxy NGINX that didn't have the rights to write temporary files...

Thank you anyway for your answer !